# Do google charge developer if the developer request for doubling or tripling the current api request limit(10,000,000 queries/day)

Tags: google-drive-api

If my app uses the google drive api and gets popular, there is a big chance that the current api request limit of 10,000,000 queries/day would not be enough. So if this does happen, chances are that I would need to request more api request from google. For anyone who have done this step, do you know if google charges you(the developer) $$$ for requesting more api request?

thanks for reading, and hope to hear from you guys ^^

Answer (score 2):

Google don't charge you for quota increases, but you have a valid reason to ask for more, and your app should be efficient in using the API.